how to upload a file ondrag with playwright
can some one help me with playwright + react? I'm trying to test a drop zone that was imported from 'react-dropzone', with a drag event. after it is dropped a div that says "Upload larger files" should appear. problem is I'm not sure how to upload files with Playwright.
test file:
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');

test.describe("home", () => {
  test('Upload ALL HTML files < 5mb', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto('http://localhost:3006/');

// Simulate drag and drop
const dropZone = await page.waitForSelector('.container-dropzone', { state: 'visible' });
await dropZone.evaluate((element) => {
  const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
  dataTransfer.items.add(new File([''], './test-files/file1.html', { type: 'text/html' }));
  const event = new DragEvent('drop', { dataTransfer });
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
});
await expect(page.getByText("Upload larger files")).toBeVisible();
  });
});

Drop Zone component:
    import React, {useMemo} from 'react';
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone';
import {Button} from "react-bootstrap";

import '../App.css';

export const DROPZONE_WEBSITE_TYPE = 'WEBSITE';
export const DROPZONE_PDF_TYPE = 'PDF';

const getPlaceholder = (type) => { 
  // som code...
}

const StyledDropzone = ({ onDrop, onTemplateSelected, className, type = DROPZONE_WEBSITE_TYPE, hideTemplate }) => {
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive, isDragAccept, isDragReject } = useDropzone({
    onDrop,
    accept: 'application/zip, application/pdf, application/x-zip-compressed, multipart/x-zip, .html, .pdf',
    maxFilesize: 0.5
  });

  const style = useMemo(() => ({
    ...baseStyle,
    ...(isDragActive ? activeStyle : {}),
    ...(isDragAccept ? acceptStyle : {}),
    ...(isDragReject ? rejectStyle : {})
  }), [
    isDragActive,
    isDragReject
  ]);

  const handleTemplateSelected = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    onTemplateSelected({
      path: type === DROPZONE_WEBSITE_TYPE ? 'example-site.zip' : 'example-doc.pdf',
      type: type === DROPZONE_WEBSITE_TYPE ? 'application/zip' : 'application/pdf',
      isTemplate: true
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className={`container-dropzone ${className || ''}`}>
      <div {...getRootProps({style})}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        {getPlaceholder(type, handleTemplateSelected, hideTemplate)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default StyledDropzone;

I tried to create an evaluate method that creates a DataTransfer and a drag event that drops the html file.
await dropZone.evaluate((element) => {
  const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
  dataTransfer.items.add(new File([''], './test-files/file1.html', { type: 'text/html' }));
  const event = new DragEvent('drop', { dataTransfer });
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
);

